# Why can't I build a campus district on this tile

Tags: civilization-6

Why can't I build a campus in the middle of these mountains?

Some items of note:
I harvested some stone off of that tile.
I annexed the tile into my city using a great merchant that allows me to do so.

[image: Can't build campus in the middle of these mountains]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only build districts in a 3 tile radius around your city, and that tile is 4 tiles away.

https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/District_(Civ6)

> You cannot place districts in other cities' territory, even if these other cities belong to you and the tile in question is **up to three tiles away from the City Center**

Comment: As a side note, almost everything else to do with cities respects the three-tile distance: working tiles, buying tiles, placing wonders, and culture bombing (because it adds tiles *to* the city). Only unit actions and effects - placing improvements, open/closed borders, and effects that care if you're in friendly or enemy territory - count tiles that are "yours" but away from your cities.

Comment: The good thing though is that you can harvest bonus resources and remove features (forests, rainforests) 4 and 5 tiles away from the city center if the tile belongs to the city